# class software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CommonPrefix cannot be cast to class java.lang.String

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I have fetched all the common prefix from S3  and now i want to store these common prefix in fixed size array of String, so i tried to loop over the List and tried to cat the element into Stirng but it doesnt allow me to do the same.

```
String bucketName = s3BucketDetails.getBucketName();
        String bucketPath = s3BucketDetails.getBucketPrefix();
        VehicleHeaderImage vehicleHeaderImage = null;
        List<S3Object> objList = new ArrayList<>();
        S3ResponseMessage response = null;
        String[] array;
        int index = 0;

        try {
            List<CommonPrefix> allKeysInDesiredBucket = listAllKeysInABucket(bucketName, bucketPath);
            array = new String[allKeysInDesiredBucket.size()];
            for (Object value : allKeysInDesiredBucket) {
                array[index] = (String) value;
                index++;
            }
//          for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
                objList = s3Service.getBucketObjects(bucketName, array[1]);
//          }
```

if it is not possible then how do I fetch the common prefix from `List<CommonPrefix>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a public method on the `CommonPrefix` object called `prefix()` which returns a `String` — that might be what you are looking for.

S3 sdk reference: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/CommonPrefix.html